# I can't boot my Compaq Presario desktop from an Ubuntu 12.04 usb

Tags: 12.04, installation, error-handling

I have a Compaq Presario sr2017cl desktop running Windows7. The computer locked up and when I did a hardboot and now I get a "disk read error occurred, press control alt delete to restart." 
Upon pressing control alt delete, I'm taken to the same screen. 
I have a parted magic disc that I've used recently on a Dell laptop that worked beautifully. I can't get the Compaq to boot from the dvd even when I change the boot order in the bios, nor can I get it to start from the Windows 7 recovery cd.
I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on a usb drive that I used to install ubuntu on a HP laptop which I'm using right now. When I try to boot the desktop from that same usb, it won't boot from it and I get the same disk read error over and over. 
I've researched this extensively online and the only answers I come up with are to change the boot order, or use f10 to choose what to boot from. I've tried that repeatedly to no avail. I've also tried unplugging the power, holding the power button for a full minute and powering back up. so far, nothing has worked. I'm at my wits end. I know both the parted magic dvd and usb work correctly but I can't get them to work on this bleeping computer. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error message indicates a hard drive problem.  Check your BIOS to see how the drive controller is set.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might have a corrupt hard drive. Try purchasing an external hard drive adapter and see if the hard drive will pop up for available use. If your hard drive does not become available when using the external hard drive adapter on the other computer you are using to make this process happen, you will know if you do or do not have a damaged hard drive.

If it does work, then you will know at least that your hard drive is working properly.